# Excel Power Query - add conditional column by looking up data from another Table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking to add a conditional column in power query by looking up data from another table.

As an example, my lookup data is as follows:

[image: Lookup master Table]

My data is as follows:

[image: Data]

Now I want to check if the number in my data is between Begin & End of my Master data & if the condition is satisfied, then I want to add a column by coping the corresponding "Digits" Cell to my Data. The result should look like this:

[image: Resulting Table after lookup & adding column]

Can someone point me on how to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your your top table into powerquery with the query name **LookupQuery** and file ... close and load. It should have the column names you show

Then load the middle source table into powerquery and Add column ...  custom column... with formula

```
= Table.SelectRows(LookupQuery,(x) => [Data] >= x[Begin] and [Data] <=x[End] )[Digits]{0}
```

full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(LookupQuery,(x) => [Data] >= x[Begin] and [Data] <=x[End] )[Digits]{0})
in #"Added Custom"
```

**another way** is to do a match based on length of the digits. This would work better for large data sets Load your middle source data into powerquery and

add column ... custom column ... with formula

```
=  Text.Length(Text.From([Data]))
```

merge your data with with lookup query and replace the formula in the formula bar with :

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, Table.AddColumn(LookupQuery, "Custom", each Text.Length(Text.From([Begin]))), {"Custom"}, "LookupQuery", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

expand the Digits column

full code for the 2nd method:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Length(Text.From([Data]))),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, Table.AddColumn(LookupQuery, "Custom", each Text.Length(Text.From([Begin]))), {"Custom"}, "LookupQuery", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded LookupQuery" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "LookupQuery", {"Digits"}, {"Digits"})
in #"Expanded LookupQuery"
```

Comment: I have been using this formula for various table lookups to extract data that I want automatically. However I noticed that its really taking a long time for the queries to be completed. I am taking about hours. My is a latest i5 CPU Quad Core with 16GB RAM. Still it takes hours and hours for the query to finish. Any idea why?

Comment: Which formula? X=> or the other one?  The merge method is going to be faster then the x method for large data sets I believe

Comment: Yes the X=> formula. The reason I can't use Text length merge is because my data varies. The Table.Selectrows works perfectly fine except that even for small table lookups (table sizes < 2000 rows) it takes almost 4-5 hours!!! why is that? Any idea?

Comment: In LookupQuery =   try adding LookupQuery = Table.Buffer(),

Comment: Tried. But it doesn't help. The query is still slow.

Comment: Ok. Tell me again how your data varies so that you cant use Text.Length()

Comment: Basically I am using your formula to lookup tables to match cells from two tables (numbers, strings or combination of both) & get another cell from the same row. Much like how we use vlookup. So trying to match length wouldn't work since the string length would vary.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand that, so can't help